# Fwrite not writing inside of if statement

Tags: php

I have a fwrite writing each business' page but i want it so that it only shows the html of the page  when you go to the url with a valid session so i wrote 
  fwrite($fp,"

However when it writes the page it writes this . The isset statement is gone from the if statement.

```
    <?php

$recid = $_POST['recid'];
$username = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ownername = $_POST['ownername'];

include ("connection.php");


$result = $db->query("UPDATE users SET verified='y' WHERE recid='$recid'"); 

$doctype      = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
$htmlOpen     = "<html>";
$head         = "<head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>
                 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'> </script>
                 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js'> </script> 
                 <script src='Scripts/dropdown.js'> </script> 
                 <link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/businesspages.css'> 
                 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'> 
                 <script src='Scripts/postdata.js'> </script>
                 </head>";

$bodyOpen     = "<body>";
$header       = "<div id='header'> </div>";
$wcImage      = "<img src='wc.png' id='wc'>";
$accountTable = "<table id='accountinfo'> 
                 <tr> <td id='accountinfotd1'> </td> </tr> 
                 <tr> <td id='accountinfotd2'>{$username}</td> </tr> 
                 <tr> <td id='accountinfotd3'>{$ownername}</td> </tr> 
                 </table>";

$linksTable   = "<table id='links'> 

                <tr> <td> <input type='text' id='post' placeholder='Post' name='post'> </td> </tr>

                <tr> <td> <img src='images/profile.jpg' id='profile'> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <div id='profileDiv'>
                <table>
                <tr> 
                <td> <input type='password' id='changePSW' name='changePSW' placeholder='Change Password' tabindex=2> </td>
                <td> <input type='password' id='verifyPSW' name='verifyPSW' placeholder='Verify Password' tabindex=3> </td>
                <td> <input type='image' id='changePSWBtn' src='images/changeBtn.jpg' name='changePSWBtn'> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                <td> <input type='text' id='changeLA' name='changeLA' placeholder='Latitude' tabindex=6> </td>
                <td> <input type='text' id='changeLO' name='verifyPSW' placeholder='Longatude' tabindex=7> </td>
                <td> <input type='image' id='changeLLBtn' src='images/changeBtn.jpg' name='changeLLBtn'> </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <img src='images/legal.jpg' id='legal'> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <div id='legalDiv'>
                <a href='Legal_Documents/termsofuseweb.pdf' target='_blank'> Web Terms Of Use </a> </br>
                <a href='Legal_Documents/termsofuseios.pdf' target='_blank'> iOS Terms Of Use </a> </br>
                <a href='Legal_Documents/enduserlisenceagreement.pdf' target='_blank'> End Of User Licensee </a>
                </div> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <img src='images/help.jpg' id='help'> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <div id='helpDiv'> 
                <p> If you need help you can contact Phil Pilon or Matt Muehlemann info@wolfeboroconnection.com </p>
                </div> </td> </tr> 

                </table>";

$bodyClose    = "</body>";
$htmlClose    = "</html>";
$isset = "{$_SESSION['id']}";

$filename = str_replace(" ","_", trim($username) ); 
mkdir("Business_Pages/" . $filename."/");

if( $fp = fopen("Business_Pages/" . $filename . "/" . $filename . ".php", "w") )
{
  fwrite($fp,"<?php session_start();");
  fwrite($fp, "if(isset({$_SESSION['id']})) { ?");
  fwrite($fp, $doctype.$htmlOpen.$head.$bodyOpen.$header.$wcImage.$accountTable.$linksTable.$bodyClose.$htmlClose);
  fwrite($fp,"<?php } else { echo \"User not logged in\";} ?>");
  fclose($fp);
}
```

This is the page it fwrites

```
    <?php session_start();if() { ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>
                 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'> </script>
                 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js'> </script> 
                 <script src='Scripts/dropdown.js'> </script> 
                 <link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/businesspages.css'> 
                 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'> 
                 <script src='Scripts/postdata.js'> </script>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                 <div id='header'> </div><img src='wc.png' id='wc'><table id='accountinfo'> 
                 <tr> <td id='accountinfotd1'> </td> </tr> 
                 <tr> <td id='accountinfotd2'>test </td> </tr> 
                 <tr> <td id='accountinfotd3'></td> </tr> 
                 </table><table id='links'> 

                <tr> <td> <input type='text' id='post' placeholder='Post' name='post'> </td> </tr>

                <tr> <td> <img src='images/profile.jpg' id='profile'> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <div id='profileDiv'>
                <table>
                <tr> 
                <td> <input type='password' id='changePSW' name='changePSW' placeholder='Change Password' tabindex=2> </td>
                <td> <input type='password' id='verifyPSW' name='verifyPSW' placeholder='Verify Password' tabindex=3> </td>
                <td> <input type='image' id='changePSWBtn' src='images/changeBtn.jpg' name='changePSWBtn'> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                <td> <input type='text' id='changeLA' name='changeLA' placeholder='Latitude' tabindex=6> </td>
                <td> <input type='text' id='changeLO' name='verifyPSW' placeholder='Longatude' tabindex=7> </td>
                <td> <input type='image' id='changeLLBtn' src='images/changeBtn.jpg' name='changeLLBtn'> </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <img src='images/legal.jpg' id='legal'> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <div id='legalDiv'>
                <a href='Legal_Documents/termsofuseweb.pdf' target='_blank'> Web Terms Of Use </a> </br>
                <a href='Legal_Documents/termsofuseios.pdf' target='_blank'> iOS Terms Of Use </a> </br>
                <a href='Legal_Documents/enduserlisenceagreement.pdf' target='_blank'> End Of User Licensee </a>
                </div> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <img src='images/help.jpg' id='help'> </td> </tr> 

                <tr> <td> <div id='helpDiv'> 
                <p> If you need help you can contact Phil Pilon or Matt Muehlemann info@wolfeboroconnection.com </p>
                </div> </td> </tr> 

                </table></body></html><?php } else { echo "User not logged in";} ?>
```

Comment: Can you narrow down to a small snippet to reproduce the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you are using the following line:

```
fwrite($fp, "if(isset({$_SESSION['id']})) { ?");
```

Because you are using double quotes it means that the session value `{$_SESSION['id']}` will be parsed by PHP, before being written to the file via fwrite. If you change your quotes to single quotes you wont have this problem, as PHP will leave single quoted strings alone — i.e. not parse them for variables:

```
fwrite($fp, 'if(isset($_SESSION["id"])) { ?');
```

You should also remove the surrounding curly braces on the session var, unless you want your php to be erroneous when it is reparsed.

This is all assuming that the outcome you want in the file is:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["id"])) { ?
```

Comment: that was exactly the outcome i wanted

Comment: THANK YOU!!  Drove me nuts for minutes ;)  +1